# Can I compile an excel file in a C# WPF program and use it in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I'm making a program that you put data, works it and then writes an excel file with the results.

The thing is, given the nature of the excel that has produce the program, I found out that is easier to just have a "template" excel file (With the headers), copy it with the appropriate name and then fill it.

My problem is that the people I am working for sometimes can be a little bit grumpy and they wanted a single executable, not the executable AND the template. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to compile the template onto the project and work it in program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Embedd it as a resource in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed the Excel file as a resource. Access the Excel file as follows:

```
var streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(<Pack URI of Excel>));

using (var stream = streamResourceInfo.Stream)
{
    // Load stream into Excel object?
}
```